# ASP.NET authentication question

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I have following code in an aspx page:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            lblAuthentication.Text = 
            "Authenticated user: " + User.Identity.Name;
        else
            lblAuthentication.Text = 
            "User not authenticated. Anonymous access ";

        lblWindowsIdentity.Text = 
            "Windows identity: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

    }   // Page_Load()
```

web.config settings are as follows:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

When logged in as Bob who is Administrator I get following output

```
Authenticated user: Bob-PC\Bob
Windows identity: Bob-PC\Bob
```

Additional code shows me:

```
    Administrator: True 
    User: True 
    Guest: False 
    PowerUser: False 
    AccountOperator: False 
    SystemOperator: False
```

Then I switch user (Windows Vista), log in as Guest, browse to the same website and I get the same output???

```
Authenticated user: Bob-PC\Bob
Windows identity: Bob-PC\Bob

    Administrator: True 
    User: True 
    Guest: False 
    PowerUser: False 
    AccountOperator: False 
    SystemOperator: False
```

Why do I get the same output for different users?

Comment: Make sure there is no caching. Are you using IE? Are you running the website locally?

Comment: Unless you are using impersonation you wont be picking up any credentials of the browsing user...

Answer (score 0):

WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name is he identity under which the IIS thread is running.

Answer (score 0):

Because the website is operating under the context of Bob-PC\Bob rather than the user you are logged in as. The calls you are making are looking at the website process (not what is going on outside the website[rest of windows]).

If you are using IIS you can change the identity that the worker process runs under by modifying the properties of the application pool that hosts the website....

NOTE: you can use impersonation in .net to force IIS to operate under the context of the browsing user. And this is the way that you would secure an app running on a LAN for example with a windows network running. But in order for this to work you have to use IE as other browsers dont pass the domain authentication credentials).

Comment: Hello.

you write "if you are using IIS you can change the identity that the worker process runs under by modifying the properties of the application pool that hosts the website..."

how can you do that?

thank you

Comment: IIS7 --> go to application pool (right click), go to advanced settings, go to 'process model' --> change identity, recycle application pool.

Comment: You can use process explorer to really see what is going on under the covers with processes in terms of credentials/users. Let me know how this goes and mark as correct if okay....